# Center one column of gridview

Tags: c#, css, gridview

I have several gridviews throughout my C# web app that uses CSS to give them all the same look/feel. On just a few grids I need one column header to be centered but not the rest. I have tried setting them in the designer/HTML with:

```
<HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
```

and on dataBinding and DataBound with:

```
GridViewRow gvr = this.GridView1.HeaderRow;
gvr.Cells[1].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
```

How best to override the CSS or set the column's horizontal alignment after bound and CSS applied?

Comment: `Header` and `Center` do not make good tags, while `C#` and `CSS` do. People with `C#` and `CSS` knowledge will be able to answer your question, but one can't really have `Header` or `Center` knowledge. People generally follow tags and thus see appropriate questions.

Comment: John Saunders and Dukeling. Sorry but I am still in the dark here are we talking about the title of my question or tags you add to the end? Perhaps both? Sorry if I titled my question poorly or chose bad tags. My intent was to find some help with my C-Sharp web application. I am using CSS to format a consistant look on my grids but need to have one column centered from time to time. Not a big deal to me, but it is to my client. Wish I had a time machine so I could see what the original title was and the original tags. Not trying to be difficult, just confused at this point.